# Onsen UI AngularJS Lazy Load (infinite scroll) pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, onsen-ui

i have tried this approach to do lazy loading but the method requests and loads item one by one.

[Asynchronous Calls](https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#LazyRepeatAsync)

However, is it possible to request a list of data? For example the approach like below link using Endless Scroll:

[AngularJS Endless Scroll Demo](http://codepen.io/davidchin/full/oXbYEg)

I have tried to apply Endless Scroll to my Onsen UI project but there is error:

```
TypeError: child.scope is not a function
at EndlessScroller.<anonymous> (angular-endless-scroll.js:519)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:1187)
at Function.n.extend.each (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at n.fn.n.each (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at EndlessScroller._getDimension (angular-endless-scroll.js:514)
at EndlessScroller.clean (angular-endless-scroll.js:296)
at EndlessScroller.check (angular-endless-scroll.js:145)
at EndlessScroller.<anonymous> (angular-endless-scroll.js:266)
at angular.js:1188
at angular.js:17855
```

I am still a newb of AngularJS and Onsen UI, I spent a couple of time on this issue and I do hope to figure out a solution to do Lazy Load Pagination. Thank you for advance!